# RoR: SaaS Examples (Code/Tutorials)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas

I'm an RoR newbie working to create a hosted task management/workflow solution and am looking for examples (especially code) of how to properly architect it.  As with typical SaaS products, I will have multiple subscription plans, with varying capabilities (for example: the assignment of tasks to other users by the paying subscriber) and data storage.  Could someone point me in the direction of tutorials/examples (I've searched but haven't had much luck.)  Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not free, but my [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that covers at least some aspects of SaaS product, specifically the organisation in different subdomains for each user: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog with necessary changes that need to done while developing a SaaS application. I have written in PHP using Zend Framework but the same concept can be applied to Ruby On Rails also. Check it from:  [SaaS application development using PHP in Zend Framework](http://goo.gl/ftTMZ)